# On click and visibility for 2 DIV

Tags: javascript

With this code I want setVisibility 2 DIV, for the moment there is only 1 DIV = "Note-question-sub", i want add an other div :

```
<label for="note2" title="Passable">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-note btn-xs" onclick="setVisibility('Note-question-sub', 'block');">
        <i class="fa fa-plus rouge" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span class="sr-only">Passable</span>
    </a>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="note" id="note2" />
</label>
```

This is my JS code:

```
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: So amend the function to take 2 parameters, or call it twice...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call **`setVisibility`** twice

```
<label for="note2" title="Passable">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-note btn-xs" onclick="setVisibility('Note-question-sub', 'block'); setVisibility('YOUR_SECOND_DIV', 'block'); "><!--YOUR_SECOND_DIV is your second div-->
        <i class="fa fa-plus rouge" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span class="sr-only">Passable</span>
    </a>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="note" id="note2" />
</label>
```